# error when running python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, manage.py

I have a new server just installed. Everything seems to be fine but when i run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

it generates follow error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 109, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 190, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 51, in create_permissions
    content_type=ctype
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 138, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 360, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 553, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1436, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 791, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 175, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 89, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x99\xAF\xE9\xBB\x9E...' for column 'name' at row 1
```

All the tables and fields, in fact, created automatically without observable problem. I just wanna get rid of this error becoz the same thing does not happen in my old server with exactly the same project running on it.

Comment: I have solved this myself.

Change all the collation of ALL tables AND fields to utf (utf8_general_ci) stops the error beautifully.

Comment: @OCD If you answer your own question and then accept that answer, other people who have the same problem can search for this problem and then see that it has an accepted answer. So the don't have to suffer the same debugging. (And we can vote up your answer :-)

Comment: hi Johan, but in 24 hours, i cannot ans my own question, i have to wait until then and the system suggested me to use comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am answering it here so that other people can have answer of same problem:

As said by Bill Kary: 
He have solved this himself. Change all the collation of ALL tables AND fields to utf (utf8_general_ci) stops the error beautifully.